# How to create changelog for table?

Tags: mysql, debugging, changelog

I need to create a change history of table rows when a certain field is changed. So what I wanted to do is create a trigger on table update. When the field `txta` changes, I want the whole row to get copied over to `debug`which is a cloned version of `msser_210` with an added column for datetime at the end, without data. I would like to add `NOW()` on change so I would have a timestamp. This is what I have tried to far:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER history_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON msser_210
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF OLD.txta != NEW.txta
        THEN
            INSERT INTO `debug_history` (`idpm`,`posn`,`prnb`,`doid`,`ofcr`,`pidm`,`hitm`,`sitm`,`item`,`dsca`,`igid`,`kitm`,`leng`,`widt`,`hght`,`thik`,`radi`,`quas`,`wght`,`effc`,`colr`,`bdat`,`edat`,`back`,`cuid`,`intb`,`aggr`,`unqu`,`oqua`,`unsq`,`stoc`,`allo`,`hall`,`tqan`,`bqan`,`pkey`,`pric`,`cvqs`,`unsp`,`disc`,`dart`,`ksid`,`anhg`,`txta`,`txti`,`mndn`, `changedate`) VALUES (OLD.idpm,OLD.posn,OLD.prnb,OLD.doid,OLD.ofcr,OLD.pidm,OLD.hitm,OLD.sitm,OLD.item,OLD.dsca,OLD.igid,OLD.kitm,OLD.leng,OLD.widt,OLD.hght,OLD.thik,OLD.radi,OLD.quas,OLD.wght,OLD.effc,OLD.colr,OLD.bdat,OLD.edat,OLD.back,OLD.cuid,OLD.intb,OLD.aggr,OLD.unqu,OLD.oqua,OLD.unsq,OLD.stoc,OLD.allo,OLD.hall,OLD.tqan,OLD.bqan,OLD.pkey,OLD.pric,OLD.cvqs,OLD.unsp,OLD.disc,OLD.dart,OLD.ksid,OLD.anhg,OLD.txta,OLD.txti, OLD.mndn, NOW());
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

Why I want to do this is because we are having (probably) a php script with a bug that writes the same text string into every field of the database but we don't know when or why it happens neither which script it does. Is there maybe a more elegant solution?

UPDATE: I found the option to "Track Changes" in phpMyAdmin, but apparently it does not track our programs php-issued  `UPDATE` queries, the `DROP` and `CREATE TABLE` statements from PHP are tracked though. If I issue an `UPDATE`  via phpMyAdmin, it is tracked though. Long story short I went back to my original plan with the trigger.

UPDATE2: found the answer out myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `debug_history` is a cloned via pypMyAdmin from the original table. It got an additional changedate column appended manually.

```
ALTER TABLE debug_history ADD COLUMN changedate DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
```

I decided because there was no other way that I would have to type all the names myself. Because I am lazy I got a recent SQL dump, copied an `INSERT INTO`-Statement from the file that is used to rebuild `msser_210` and altered the values.

I added an extra row with an autoincrement line, dropped the primary key and set the new primary key to the new row.

```
ALTER TABLE debug_history DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE debug_history ADD COLUMN changenumber INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I now have a working changelog, triggered on change in `txta` field (Please see the question for the trigger with the original format). I renamed the `txta` column in the `debug_history` to `txta_old` and created a new column `txta_new`.

```
ALTER TABLE debug_history CHANGE txta txta_old TEXT NOT NULL $$
ALTER TABLE debug_history ADD COLUMN txta_new TEXT NOT NULL AFTER txta_old $$
```

Afterwards I had to modify the trigger because I manually had to copy all the names..

```
DROP TRIGGER history_trigger
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER history_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON msser_210
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF OLD.txta != NEW.txta
        THEN
            INSERT INTO `debug_history` (`idpm`,`posn`,`prnb`,`doid`,`ofcr`,`pidm`,`hitm`,`sitm`,`item`,`dsca`,`igid`,`kitm`,`leng`,`widt`,`hght`,`thik`,`radi`,`quas`,`wght`,`effc`,`colr`,`bdat`,`edat`,`back`,`cuid`,`intb`,`aggr`,`unqu`,`oqua`,`unsq`,`stoc`,`allo`,`hall`,`tqan`,`bqan`,`pkey`,`pric`,`cvqs`,`unsp`,`disc`,`dart`,`ksid`,`anhg`,`txta_old`,`txta_new`,`txti`,`mndn`, `changedate`) VALUES (OLD.idpm,OLD.posn,OLD.prnb,OLD.doid,OLD.ofcr,OLD.pidm,OLD.hitm,OLD.sitm,OLD.item,OLD.dsca,OLD.igid,OLD.kitm,OLD.leng,OLD.widt,OLD.hght,OLD.thik,OLD.radi,OLD.quas,OLD.wght,OLD.effc,OLD.colr,OLD.bdat,OLD.edat,OLD.back,OLD.cuid,OLD.intb,OLD.aggr,OLD.unqu,OLD.oqua,OLD.unsq,OLD.stoc,OLD.allo,OLD.hall,OLD.tqan,OLD.bqan,OLD.pkey,OLD.pric,OLD.cvqs,OLD.unsp,OLD.disc,OLD.dart,OLD.ksid,OLD.anhg,OLD.txta,NEW.txta,OLD.txti, OLD.mndn, NOW());
        END IF;
    END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As per the OP's comment, clearly the context is very specific.  An infrastructure team without access to (or the ability to feedback and direct the development team's) code needs a mechanism by which to log table changes on a production database.

**Warnings about using triggers**:

Triggers can be tricky to debug, not least because they're transparent and it is never obvious to someone new looking at your code that a trigger is performing some action behind the scenes.  (I speak from experience.)  They can also cause issues on [replicated](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/09/29/why-audit-logging-with-triggers-in-mysql-is-bad-for-replication/), multi-master and clustered installations.  (Again, I speak from experience.)  Also if they fail for some unrelated reason (e.g. the table they write to is broken), the *entire* transaction can/will fail (InnoDB) - which might not be what you want.  (Especially with non-essential "debug" functions.)

Otherwise, triggers are a perfectly valid tool.  **And in your specific scenario, probably the best bet available to you.**

There are several other options available to you, two of which I would highlight:

**Stored procedures as an access layer to data**

If you're very data centric and you already have business logic inside the database - (a hotly debated topic, I'm not here arguing that you should or should not have business logic in the database) then reading and writing to the database through stored procedures has a clear advantage.

Any *transactionally tied* logic can be inserted into these stored procedures such that the *transactionally unsafe* caller (PHP, being a common example) only needs to call 1 query (`call sp_insert_tablename(123, 'abc')`) and transactional safety can be enforced by the database.

Temporary debug logic can be added to these stored procedures and enabled/disabled by a flag in a settings table, session variable, final argument, whatever you please.

**Data abstraction layer/library**

Similar principle.  Find a data abstraction layer for your client (assuming you have access to alter it's internals).  For a PHP or .NET web app there are several popular choices, all of which allow you to override (extend through code inheritance) the save/delete operations to perform any additional actions you want - exactly as for stored procedures (but with the logic maintained inside models in the client).

If you want a specific example, you'll need to give us more information on what stack/language/framework(s) you're using

With both options, make sure you appropriately handle error scenarios.

Comment: Tbh the program is a lost cause and I am not its developer, I can't code php. I am the servers SysAdmin and I was told to log everything written to the given database, so the developers could debug (there arent even unit tests etc.) so that is nice and all but nothing I can really do about it

Comment: That's absolutely fine.  Then I would suggest my answer still answers your question - "Otherwise, triggers are a perfectly valid tool."  Stick with the solution you've come up with, that'll be fine.  The experience I had with triggers was due to exactly the same scenario you're in - the guy who put them in there was forced to.  As part of a wider topic, if I were in your position, I'd be raising my hand (do you have formal process for infrastructure to interface developers, like devops?) and saying "I'm being forced to do this, which is fine, but it'll bite us, and I want that on record".

Comment: I tried that, but the amount of colums in the new tables is different because I added a column for the changedate and wanted to set it aswell

Comment: That's a common problem when duplicating data across tables.  You could limit the fields you copy, by explicitly naming a subset of fields, doing it automatically (like in your example) will break both the trigger and potentially the entire transaction when scheme changes occur.  Prepared statements could hack around it (building the query via code), but it really would be a hack.

Comment: I found a solution where I would have to manually type each name, but I don't want to copy all the column names manually. There must be a faster way. I don't mind the hacky-ness of this, since I can just drop the trigger after I'm done